# Limitation of Python SDK for Google Cloud Dataflow over Java SDK

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

What are the limitations of using python SDK for Google Cloud Dataflow over Java SDK ? From the Google Cloud Dataflow documentation I found out that Python SDK currently doesnt support autoscaling for streaming. Also seems like there is a limitation on using Python3. Is there anything else ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation for exactly what features are in Java vs Python isn't clearly summarized anywhere. Would you mind discussing your problem a bit, and we can help you make an informed choice? I.e. which source/sinks you want to use, etc. You can find API references for the two APIs as well. 
https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python/

Comment: We are just starting to adopt Google cloud dataflow in our organisation and want to decide which SDK to go with. Don't want to end up writing in two languages

Comment: If that's your concern that you may have access to fewer features then I would recommend Java, since it generally supports more features than Python and has higher performance. Python pipelines can be a little bit simpler to write, as a bit less syntax is required though, that's the main advantage.

Comment: I also recommend becoming familiar with the existing provided template pipelines. They solve many use cases (such as ETL, moving data between locations). You can solve many problems without writing code at all, just providing parameters.

Take a look at the "Create Job From Template" link in the dataflow UI to see a list of template pipelines you can run.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/executing-templates